# Why I cannot use transforms.ifft2?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have the following imports

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
from fastmri.data import transforms
```

After some lines of code I have the following two line:

```
slice_kspace2=transforms.to_tensor(slice_kspace)
slice_image=transforms.ifft2(slice_kspace2)
```

The first line works fine so transforms.to_tensor is fine but not the second line I get the following error.

```
File "testForF.py", line 32, in <module>
    slice_image=transforms.ifft2(slice_kspace2)
AttributeError: module 'fastmri.data.transforms' has no attribute 'ifft2'
```

Any help please. Where can I find the "transforms" which has ifft2, that all the people are using while working on fastMRI data?

Answer (score 1):

The fastmri module function to_tensor converts it to a pytorch tensor. Now you can use the pytorch function ifft over here
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/fft.html#torch-fft-module and specify the axes or convert it to CuPy as given over here https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/interoperability.html with its DLpack method if your requirements are more numpy like.

Sample with CuPy

```py
    import cupy
    import torch

    from torch.utils.dlpack import to_dlpack
    from torch.utils.dlpack import from_dlpack

    import h5py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from fastmri.data import transforms
```

```py
    slice_kspace2=transforms.to_tensor(slice_kspace)
    dx = to_dlpack(slice_kspace2)
    cx = cupy.fromDlpack(dx)
    slice_image = cupy.fft.ifft2(cx)
```

Sample with Pytorch

```py
    import h5py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import torch
    from fastmri.data import transforms
```

```py
    slice_kspace2=transforms.to_tensor(slice_kspace)
    slice_image = torch.fft.ifftn(slice_kspace2, (-2, -1))
```

Edit:
Currently the fastmri module names its FFT transforms as `fastmri.fft2c` and `fastmri.ifft2c` so maybe that's what you are looking for?(Note they are centered FFT and not the traditional FFTs, which is what that c means)
Also it seems that the fastmri module has a packaged a banding removal example https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastMRI/tree/master/banding_removal
which uses what you are recommending. Do note that the FFT methods that fastmri are using are internally just torch functions with a few decorations like being centered, so using the torch modules should be your first preference.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will check if it works next Monday (14/12/2020). But can you tell me how to use transforms, which is the main question? There may be other methods in "transmorms" which I might need for my work.

Comment: May i ask if you have experience of working with fastmri data? I looked the paper you mentioned but never saw any code? How do you know that they are using transforms.ifft2?

Comment: No, I don't have experience with fastmri but their codebase was simple enough to understand. I mentioned this link https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastMRI/tree/master/banding_removal which has the code. A simple search of the code showed that they are using a custom version of fastmri that has internal support for ifft2. Don't get so hung up on where FFT functions are coming from as long as its a reputable library( Numpy, torch, scipy). They have tests to ensure that the code is correct and will have support for many more functions.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. My experince with Linux and python is ony few weeks; so still in the early stage of learing and do not have any knowledge of the existing packages,

Comment: Yes, fastmri.ifft2c works. Thank you so much. But, may I please ask how did you find out that, (what search method) "Edit: Currently the fastmri module names its FFT transforms as fastmri.fft2c and fastmri.ifft2c" I searched the internet for 5 days and falied to find this answer. Would you please let me know? Do you know .py file which produces inverse Fourier Transform. When I check the fastmri.fftc.py I see they had used the torch.Tensor version and then changed some staff from that one. I am looking for .py file which does ifft. BTW you deserve the bounty

Comment: Vscode, my IDE, gets the credit.  A simple search of the FFT in the codebase gave quite a few results and then I just narrowed them down to ones that were relevant. Fastmri doesn't have generated documentation anywhere so it is understandable that googling the issue didn't work. As for your second question, torch recently deprecated its torch.ifft and torch.fft functions for a new torch.fft module. Hence the library is checking which function to use based on the version of torch. I don't know which torch version you have but if it is greater than 1.7 then you will be using torch.ifft2c_new

Comment: Please accept the answer if you think your problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you Niteya.